# Inline assembly: Saving the stack pointer on ARM

Tags: c++, arm, inline-assembly, osdev, keil

I'm working on building an RTOS from the ground up and getting stuck on some of the inline assembly used for the context switch. I have a thread object that currently stores the stack pointer for that specific thread and a function pointer.

In the context switch code, I want to push R4-11 onto the stack, modify the stack pointer, and pop R4-11 off the new stack. I'm using keil5 to compile, but I'm not able to store the stack pointer right before swapping stacks. Here's what I've tried

```
// My intent: OsCurrent->sp = sp;
asm("LDR    r0,%0"
            :"=r"(OsCurrent)
            :
            :);
asm("LDR    r1,[r0]");
asm("MOV    r4, sp");
asm("STR    r4,[r1]");
```

However this gives me the following compiler error:

```
Rtos.hpp(127): error: invalid operand for instruction
        asm("LDR    r0,%0"
            ^
<inline asm>(1): note: instantiated into assembly here
    LDR    r0,r0
```

What is the proper syntax for trying to store this?

I've also tried `asm("LDR    r0,=OsCurrent");` in place of the extended asm line, but I was getting a linker error about not finding the OsCurrent symbol. I think that's related to name cloberring in cpp? Correct me if I'm wrong here

For reference, here is the full code:

```
#ifndef RTOS_HPP
#define RTOS_HPP

#include <cstdint>

typedef void (*OsTask)();

class Rtos
{
public:
    using Address = uint32_t *;
    
    static void SVTask()
    {
        //ContextSwitch( (uint32_t *)OsCurrent, (uint32_t *)OsNext );
      
        if ( OsCurrent != nullptr ) {
            // Push R4-R7 onto the stack
            asm("PUSH    {R4-R7}");
            // Push R8-R11 onto the stack
            asm("MOV     R4, R8");
            asm("MOV     R5, R9");
            asm("MOV     R6, R10");
            asm("MOV     R7, R11");
            asm("PUSH    {R4-R7}");
          
            // Rtos::OsCurrent->sp = sp;
            asm("LDR    r0,%[curr]"
                :
                :[curr]"r"(OsCurrent)
                :);
            asm("LDR    r1,[r0]");
            asm("MOV    r4, sp");
            asm("STR    r4,[r1]");
            
        }
        
        
        // sp = OsNext->sp;
        asm("LDR    r1,=next");
        asm("LDR    r1,[r0]");
        asm("LDR    r4,[r1]");
        asm("MOV    sp,r4");
      
        OsCurrent = OsNext;
        
        // Pop R8-R11 off the stack
        asm("POP     {R4-R7}");
        asm("MOV     R8, R4");
        asm("MOV     R9, R5");
        asm("MOV     R10, R6");
        asm("MOV     R11, R7");
        
        // Pop R4-R7 off the stack
        asm("POP {r4-r7}");
            
        asm("CPSIE   I ");
    }

    void* sp;
    OsTask handler;

    static inline Rtos* volatile OsCurrent = nullptr; // Pointer to current thread
    static inline Rtos* volatile OsNext = nullptr;    // Pointer to next thread
};

#endif // RTOS_HPP
```

Comment: Why not just `"str sp, %0" : "=m" (OsCurrent->sp)`? PS: better not use separate asm statements.

Comment: The `"=r"` constraint tells the compiler that `OsCurrent` has to be in a register for this asm statement. If that's what you wanted, `str` to a register makes no sense and you would use `mov` instead. Or, change to `"=m"` as Jester said so the compiler uses a memory address for `OsCurrent` in this asm statement.

Comment: If you want to use GNU C Basic Asm statements (no constraints to tell the compiler which registers you're stepping on), your function needs to be `__attribute__((naked))`.  But then you can't use anything except `asm("")` statements in the function body.  This code is totally unsafe and will almost certainly break when you overwrite the register the compiler's using to keep a pointer to static data, and/or when its asm steps on your registers since you have a bunch of asm statements that read registers they didn't write!! https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended

Comment: `LDR    r0,=OsCurrent` would only link if it was a variable at global scope, so no **name mangling** would happen.  But you can't safely read/write variables in inline asm statements without a `"memory"` clobber or telling the compiler about it via a constraint like `"+m"(OsCurrent)`.

Comment: I added the tag "osdev" and removed "rtos" to make room (maximum of 5 tags)

Comment: It's normal to write your whole context switch function in pure asm, so it looks to the compiler like an opaque function call (which clobbers the call-clobbered registers, such as r0..3).  Also, **GNU C inline asm doesn't officially *support* modifying the stack pointer**, i.e. the documentation says * the compiler requires the value of the stack pointer to be the same after an asm statement as it was on entry to the statement.* so changing it is UB.  If it breaks, you get to keep both pieces.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers-1

Comment: you need to be doing this in real asm not inline.

Comment: look at other rtos impementations to understand how they are doing it for this target

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm actually not using the GNU toolchain. I'm using clang with Arm syntax according to Keil. I've tried temporarily these variables in the global scope, however I still get linker errors. I've also tried adding in the "+m"/"=m" memory clobber. This compiles at least. In the assembly, it replaces all the variable reference with something like this: "r0,[pc,#56]  ; @0x08000618" However the data at this ROM location is garbage as far as I can tell and the RAM address for the variable I'm wanting to access can be seen in ROM a couple a bytes offset from the "0x08000618" it lists.

Comment: @old_timer Do you have any examples you can point me to? I tried to find the freeRtos source code, but I wasn't able to see any asm files

Comment: @Jester I'd actually tried this ("str sp, %0" : "=m" (OsCurrent->sp)) already. The issue is that my micro is not an ARM thumb2 micro and storing the SP register is apparently not supported in non-thumb2 ARM

Comment: @PeterCordes Also I have now changed my function to use "__attribute__((naked))" with one big __asm statement

Comment: I don't see such a restriction about SP. What is your cpu, what options do you use to select architecture?

Comment: It's an m0. Per the arm specification, operands for STR can only be R0-R7 (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0497/a/the-cortex-m0-instruction-set/memory-access-instructions/ldr-and-str--register-offset?lang=en). Also Keil yells at me if I try to put SP as an operand while using an STM32G0, which notably do not support arm thumb

Comment: Ahha. Then again, the docs say the same for `MOV` :D I guess that's an error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure clang has the same restrictions on GNU C inline asm as GCC does.  Yes, you need to rewrite your function in pure asm, or yeah if you want it in the .cpp file, then `naked` with one `asm()`.  You might have it take two function args for where to store the old stack pointer and where to load the new, so you'll already have those addresses in registers (r0 and r1 which are volatile so don't need saving).  `stm` (or in Thumb mode, `push` specifically) should let you store most of the registers, then swap stack pointers, then `ldm` (`pop`) restores most.